# Custom Tab name reverts to original when the app is selected

Tags: facebook, tabs

I have some weird problems with facebook's custom tab name.

I made a sort of app generator and installed two test apps on a facebook page, as tabs. 
The custom tab name can be changed from inside the app and it seems to work ok at first. For example, when you access the Facebook page or a tab like Wall, Photos, etc. the tab names for the apps are the custom ones set from inside the app.

However, if you select one of those apps, the custom tab names revert to their original tab names, the ones set inside Facebook's app developer.

I tested this with 3 different browsers (Opera, Firefox and Chrome), with my account as the app administrator, with a test user for the app account and with an account not related to the app (although this account was also a tester for the app, until I removed it).

Everytime it happened the same.

Is this how the custom tab name should work or is it a sort of Facebook bug?

[edit]This is the link to the page: http://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Great-Demo/141137282644944?sk=app_215275071852681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a detailed answer for you yet but I've experienced the same and understand from several sources that this is a Facebook bug introduced lastnight with some changes.  It appears to be causing grief for a lot of people and Facebook is apparently working on a fix.

Comment: Thanks! I don't really need the details, the confirmation of the fact this is a Facebook bug is enough for me

Comment: Looks like it's now resolved.  The app we were having problems with is back to it's original state.